# Bootstrap Navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This may be a very simple fix, however I have scanned the code and cannot see the issue.

Once the menu has collapsed, the button appears - however, once clicked, there are no links to choose from. I have tried the example code on the Bootsrap components site and the same behavior persists.

The code is as followed:

```
<div id = "divHeader">
    <img src="img/header-text.png" class = "img-responsive"/>
</div>

<div id = "divContainer"> 
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Morgan Services</a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="Vag.html">VAG Tools</a></li> 
                <li><a href="tinting.html">Tinting</a></li>  
                <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li> 
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is `data-target=".navbar-collapse"` why `.`?

Comment: @KheemaPandey the bootsrap example uses it, regardless, without it the problem continues

Comment: i tried ur code it works fine

Comment: Do you have jQuery and the bootstrap JavaScript file included?

Comment: <link href ="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
  <link href ="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600" rel ="stylesheet" type ="text/css">
  <link href ="css/style.css" rel = "stylesheet">

Comment: there is a file bootstrap.js that @DenimChicken was referring to. did u include that??

Comment: @neilhem even the class works fine

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because I had the project linked to an incorrect JQuery file. This was solved by including:

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks for the comments